# How come the new monarch does not wear any crown?

Tags: plot-explanation, game-of-thrones

In the last episode of Game of Thrones,

> Bran is made the King of the Six Kingdoms

While there is no longer Iron Throne, I'd expect the new king to at least wear a crown. But alas, I don't remember seeing it happening.

The new Queen of the North does appear to get an elegant crown, but not the King.

How so? Is there some explanation to this, or it is just an overlook of the plot?

The crown (looks like there are two versions, one for males and one for females) was last seen on Tommen, as far as I can tell:

[image]

<sub><sup>([image source](https://gameofthrones.fandom.com/wiki/Tommen_Baratheon))</sup></sub>

Comment: Why would he need a crown when he brings his throne everywhere with him? :P

Comment: Image is for Baratheon crown I guess, so Bran either need Stark crown or some three-eyed crown

Comment: @AnkitSharma you say each house has its own crown?? That's really new to me and makes little sense, at least for me. I'd expect the same crown to just pass from king to king. But then again, I'm not familiar with the GoT universe.

Comment: @ShadowWizard That was the custom in the Seven Kingdoms before the Targaryens came. Stark Crown of Winter, Arryn Falcon Crown, Lannister Rock Crown etc were passed down from father to son until Aegon the Dragon came and took all their crowns and locked the crowns away. Aegon's own descendants created new crowns or wore previous ones if they suited their personality. E.g. Warriors like Aegon I, Maegor, Aegon II, Daeron I used Aegon I's simple crown, Peaceful ones like Aenys, Jaehaerys wore Aenys' elaborate crown, Austere ones like Aegon III, Viserys II and Aegon V wore a Aegon III's goldband

Comment: His father also wore different crown https://encrypted-tbn0.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcQWHkXM_SWSUALSlKyAzskVzfQLpClqG6Y9flxEyj97PF_y2a7H and his uncle too. He seems to be using his brother's crown

Comment: @Aegon (and Ankit if you're here) well this explains the delay for making a new crown perhaps, but still, Sansa got a new crown (probably new?) so not sure why Bran didn't get one either. Anyway thanks for the info. :)

Comment: @ShadowWizard Note the Antlers on Tommen's crown to signify the Baratheon Stag.

Answer (score 8):

**You don't wear a crown all the time**

### Crowns are usually worn only for formal / ceremonial / public events.

We only see Bran twice once he's been made King, the first time is when he's saying goodbye to Jon Snow and the second is at the first meeting of his new privy council.

Neither of these is a ceremonial event so wearing a crown would be somewhat ostentatious and Bran barely cares about being King let alone *looking the part*.

*He wasn't King at the meeting of Lords where he was made King so he would have no reason to wear a crown.*

Comment: Agree about "barely cares about being King", but the council meeting is official event, pretty sure other kings arrived with their crowns.

Comment: He wasn't king at the meeting of Lords where he was **made** king so he would have no reason to wear a crown. Rocking up wearing a crown because he *knew* he would be made king would be pretty presumptuous.

Comment: No lol, I meant the "small council", what you refer to as "his new privy council".

Comment: Not really a "formal/public" event...that's an internal admin thing.

Comment: Also do you wear a crown prior to your official coronation?

Comment: Just to establish some precedent, Robert Baratheon was not wearing a crown when he arrived in Winterfell at the beginning of Season 1.  He also does not wear a crown at the small council meeting in S1E5 when he orders assassins to kill Dany and Ned quits as Hand.  But Robert did wear a crown for public events, such as while watching the jousting tourney in S1E4.

Comment: Even Joffrey usually didn't wear his crown except to public events. He didn't wear it to that small council meeting where Tywin chastised him for feeling the need to remind everyone he's king (before sending him to bed early) https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=oRZmVvMyaog or when posing on the iron thrown itself granting audiences https://m.youtube.com/watch?v=tk5hKomP4MA

Comment: Since Bran already knew he was going to become the king, how hilarious would have been if he sat there wearing and crown and then Sansa asking him "Bran, why in the seven hell you are wearing that crown?"